# How to make 2 button component into one single row?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 button component and i want them to be in one single row

[image]

code :

```html
<template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{ item }">
   <v-btn depressed @click="view(item.book)" color="primary">View</v-btn>
   <v-btn depressed @click="viewUpdate(item.book,item.id_book)" color="primary">Update</v-btn>
</template>
```

So how to make them into one single row?

Comment: Is it the buttons that you want in single row and components to come in single row?

Comment: i mean, just the buttons for View and Update into single row, that img was the 2 button but separated into 2 row for each button

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS flex-box features:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button> Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out and here is the code :

```html
<template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{ item }" >
  <v-container grid-list-sm>
    <v-layout row justify-space-around>
      <v-flex md3>
        <v-btn depressed @click="view(item.book)" color="primary">View</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex md3>
        <v-btn depressed @click="viewUpdate(item.book,item.id_book)" color="primary">Update</v-btn> 
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```